# Finding errors on Gaussian fit from covariance matrix

Tags: python, matrix, covariance, gaussian

So, I defined a Gaussian distribution, which I later fitted to datapoints. I defined it like this:

```py
def Gauss(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean, sigma])
```

When I ask to print my popt, I get (as expected) a matrix that gives me the maximum y-value first, then the mean, and finally the sigma of the Gaussian. Now, I want to know the errors on these values, so I would like to know the error on my Gaussian fit. I thought that I could retrieve the errors from the pcov (covariance matrix), but when asked to print pcov, I get a 3X3 matrix. So, how do I find the error on my fit from this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html:

From linear algebra we know that the error of the parameters is the square root of the diagnoal entries of the covariance matrix. So for the second parameter, you would go to the matrix position [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and then take the square root. That is the error for that parameter.